Concatenating column vectors in a loop
I have a function f[a_,b_,i_]:={{a^i},{b^i}} and I want to construct a matrix
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}a & a^{2} & a^{3} & \vdots & a^{100}\\
b & b^{2} & b^{3} & \vdots & b^{100}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
i.e., the $i$-th column of the matrix A is f[a,b,i] for i ∈ {1,2,...,100}. How do I construct A programmatically in Mathematica, preferably in a loop?

The row-version would be much more simple: A=Transpose[{a^Range[1,100],b^Range[1,100]}]

f[a_, b_, i_] := {a^i, b^i}; Table[f[a, b, i], {i, 10}] // Transpose

Clear[a, b, n]
n = 10;

(Array[FromCharacterCode[96 + #1]^#2 &, {2, n}]) // MatrixForm

Outer[Power, {a, b}, Range[n]] // MatrixForm

FoldList[{a, b} # &, {a, b}, ConstantArray[1, n - 1]] // 
  Transpose // MatrixForm




The good solutions
From best to worse:
Using Outer
@Syed beat me to it. And this is the solution I like the most.
Outer[Power, {a, b}, Range[100]]

Using Table
This is the easies to undertand and still compact
Table[x^i, {x,{a,b}},{i, 1, 100}]

Unsing ReplaceAll
{a,b}^n /. n->Range[100]


Less elegant (Using Transpose or Map)
Using Table
Transpose[Table[{a^i, b^i}, {i, 1, 100}]]

Using Array
Transpose[Array[{a^#, b^#}&, 100]]
  

Using Map
Map[#^Range[100]&, {a,b}]

Using PowerRange
PowerRange[#, #^100, #]& /@ {a,b}

Using NestList
Transpose@NestList[Times[{a,b},#]&, {a,b}, 100]


Using Array and Threaded:
Thread[Array[{a, b} &, 10]]^Threaded[Range[10]] // TeXForm


$\left(
\begin{array}{cccccccccc}
 a & a^2 & a^3 & a^4 & a^5 & a^6 & a^7 & a^8 & a^9 & a^{10} \\
 b & b^2 & b^3 & b^4 & b^5 & b^6 & b^7 & b^8 & b^9 & b^{10} \\
\end{array}
\right)$


If you redefine your function without the inner List, then it's just a matter of applying your function to an argument that is a list:
f2[a_, b_, i_] := {a^i, b^i};
f2[x, y, Range@5]
(* {{x, x^2, x^3, x^4, x^5}, 
    {y, y^2, y^3, y^4, y^5}} *)

Many built in functions work naturally on List, and Power is one of them.
If you can't change your function and are stuck with
f[a_, b_, i_] := {{a^i}, {b^i}}

then just flatten the result (several ways to do that):
Catenate[f[x, y, Range@5]]

